# typescript/angular delay continuation of loop every X seconds and every X element

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

In my angular/typescript app, I have a method that takes in array of values

```
this.drawTracing(this.tracingArray);
```

Inside the implemetation of this, I want to l loop through the array, and every X element in the array, I want to delay X seconds before continuing to the next element of the array.  So for example, for every 5 records, delay continuation of the loop for 2 seconds.  How can this be done?

```
private drawTracing(tracingArray: Tracing[]) {

    for (let i=0; i < length; i++) {
         this.creatTracing(tracingArray[i]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the power of rxjs.

```
import { of, from } from 'rxjs'; 
import { delay, concatMap, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const source = of(tracingArray).pipe(
  mergeMap((x: [Tracing]) => from(x)),
  concatMap(x => of(x).pipe(delay(2000)))
);

source.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

(edit: sample with array chunks) Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-dkpg1h

edit: updated Stackblitz sample to draw dots. Basically all you would need to do is to split tracingArray into chunks (several sub-arrays), which would then be drawn every 2s.

Comment: So this is only part of the solution needed.  I only want to delay the "drawing" for every X iteration of the loop.  I don't want it to delay 2s "every" single iteration. So if I had 20 elements, I only want to issue the delay for the 5th, 10th, and 5th element

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `wait()` function with 2 sec delay

```
private drawTracing(tracingArray: Tracing[]) {

    for (let i=0; i < length; i++) {
          //2 Sec delay
          if (i===5) {
            wait(2000)
          }
         this.creatTracing(tracingArray[i]);
    }

}
```

Or you can use `setTimeOut`

```
private drawTracing(tracingArray: Tracing[]) {

    for (let i=0; i < length; i++) {
          //2 Sec delay 
         if (i === 5) {
           setTimeout(() => { console.log('2 sec delay'); }, 2000)
         }

         this.creatTracing(tracingArray[i]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only wait every 5 records, I would suggest using the [modulus (%) operator](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arithmetic.asp) to check if the index is divisible by 5. If it is evenly divisible, then the value of i % 5 will be equal to zero.

```
private drawTracing(tracingArray: Tracing[]) {

  for (let i=0; i < length; i++) {
     if(i % 5 = 0){
        setTimeout(()=> console.log('waiting'), 2000);
     }
       this.creatTracing(tracingArray[i]);
  }

}
```